# How to write the symmetric Hessian matrix for a log function?

Tags: quadratic-forms, taylor-expansion

Say f(x,y,z) = $y*ln(cos(z)+x^2)$

How would I write this as a Hessian matrix?

Would this be the right step I need to take in order to calculate the second-order Taylor polynomial for the function?